# Weblogic simple security for servlet

Tags: java, security, weblogic, web.xml

I'm trying to make a password-protected servlet running in weblogic. But I'm very restricted in a way, that I can't make configuration changes in the weblogic. I've configured the servlet for form based authentication, but I need somehow to configure roles and users. I need just a single user and a password(which won't be modified). Can this be done via deployment descriptors?
In the web.xml, I've got this and I don't know how to move on.

```
    <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>My Servlet Access</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/servlet/MyServlet*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>manager</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>My Servlet realm</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.html</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/error.html</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
<security-role>
    <role-name>manager</role-name>
</security-role>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a simple solution for servlet security here:

http://www.cs.ait.ac.th/~on/O/oreilly/java-ent/servlet/ch08_01.htm